# How to plot energy diagram using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have data file:

```
0 0 3 -0.17 6 -0.05
0 0 3 -0.23 6  0.90
0 0 3 -0.41 6  0.50
0 0 3 -0.50 6 -0.33
0 0 3 -0.20 6  0.80
```

I want to plot the figure like this which connects each point in the lines. Can you tell me how?
[image]

Comment: @theozh can you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75007412/20928504)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following suggestion uses the plotting styles `with boxxyerror`, `with vectors` and `with labels`.
The zero level gets the color of the last entry because everything is plotted on top of each other. Check the following example as starting point for further tweaking.

**Script:**

```
### energy diagram
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0 0 3 -0.17 6 -0.05   A_{one}
0 0 3 -0.23 6  0.90   B_{two}
0 0 3 -0.41 6  0.50   C_{three}
0 0 3 -0.50 6 -0.33   D_{four}
0 0 3 -0.20 6  0.80   E_{five}
EOD

set key noautotitle
set xrange [-1:8]

myWidth = 0.3

plot for [i=1:3] $Data u (column(2*i-1)):(column(i*2)):(myWidth):(0):0:xtic(i*2-1) w boxxy lw 3 lc var, \
     for [i=1:2] '' u (column(2*i-1)+myWidth):(column(i*2)): \
         (column(2*i+1)-column(2*i-1)-2*myWidth):(column(i*2+2)-column(i*2)):0 w vec nohead lw 1 dt 3 lc var, \
     '' u 5:6:7:0 w labels offset 6,0 tc var font ",16"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

From your comments: If the levels are to close such that the labels overlap, you could add an individual offset (here in column 8).
Check the following example where the data is modified that the levels B and E are very close.

**Script:**

*Edit after OP's comment*: simplifications, `with xerrorbar` instead of `with boxxyerror` and with custom xtics

*Edit 2*: simplified input data

- reduce the input data to the minimum
- add xticlabel from columnheader
- use column number as x-coordinate. Mind the difference in `...$Data u (col):col:...`: e.g. if col=1,  `(col)` is the fixed value of `1`, and `col` is the value from column 1.

```
### energy diagram with individual offset of labels
reset session

$Data <<EOD
A     B       C       Label       Offset
0.0   -0.17   -0.05   A_{one}     0
0.0   -0.23    0.90   B_{two}     0.05
0.0   -0.41    0.50   C_{three}   0
0.0   -0.50   -0.33   D_{four}    0
0.0   -0.20    0.85   E_{five}   -0.05
EOD

set key noautotitle
set errorbars 0
set offset 0.5,0.5,0,0
myWidth = 0.1

plot for [col=1:3] $Data u (col):col:(myWidth):0:xtic(columnhead(col)) w xerr lw 3 ps 0 lc var, \
     for [col=1:2] '' u (col+myWidth):col:(1-2*myWidth):(column(col+1)-column(col)):0 \
         w vec nohead lw 1 dt 3 lc var, \
     '' u (3+myWidth):($3+$5):4:0 w labels left offset 1,0 tc var font ",16"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @theozh, if two bars are close, keys are stick together. Do you know how to split them out?

Comment: @BinhThien then you have to add individual offsets (for the labels only). See modified answer.

Comment: I  would like to make this command works```set xtics (" A " 0.0, " B "  3.0, " C "  6.0)```, but only the numbers 0, 3, 6 appear. Can you help me out?

Comment: @BinhThien your `set xtics (...)` competed with `xtic(i*2-1)` in the plot command and the latter one "won". Remove the `xtic(i*2-1)`. See modified answer. Actually, do you need the columns 1,3,5 at all in your data? You could do it without

Comment: Thank you so much. it works well. I do not need columns 1, 3, 5.