# Energy diagram with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have text files like this:
NumberOfOrbital\tIt'sEnergy
I want to plot it as a horizontal sticks with a number of orbital on a left. When I am trying to plot it, I get points of given energy and number of orbital on x axis. What should I do??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show your code and your graph. Have you done a search? What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/67480420/7295599

Comment: I am a begginer when it comes to gnuplot. I only have 2 columns of my data. Therefore, this code can't be applied

Comment: Ok, if you or can't show code, then please show at least some "real" example data.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? Any response would be polite and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the gnuplot console check `help vectors` and `help labels`. I assume you are looking for something like this:

**Code:**

```
### horizontal lines with vectors and with labels
reset session

$Data <<EOD
A   1.10
B   1.50
C   1.70
D   2.10
E   2.50
F   3.30
G   3.60
EOD

unset xtic
set offset 1,1,1,1
set key noautotitle
set ylabel "Energy / a.u."

plot $Data u (0):2:(1):(0) w vec lw 2 lc "red" nohead, \
        '' u (0):2:1 w labels offset -1,0
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]