# How can I edit this code to include a for-loop to make 30 output files as well as change the title for each plot heading?

Tags: bash, for-loop, gnuplot

I have to make 30 plots (30 output SVG files). Each plot requires one input file called 'step-x' where x = 1,2,3, ... 30.
I was told to use a for-loop but am not sure how to. The code below is what I have so far.

Additionally I need to be able to change the title of the plot where it says `set title "Associative Pathway (0,1)"` and where it says `title "{/:Bold 0.84 V}"` for each individual plot.

Thanks in advance

```
#!/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/5.4.4/bin/gnuplot

set termoption font "Sans,22"
set border 15 front lt black linewidth 3.000 dashtype solid
set xrange [0:5.5]
set yrange[-5:0.1]
set title "Associative Pathway (0,1)"
set title  font "{/:Bold},23"
set xlabel "Reaction Coordinate"
set xlabel  font "{/:Bold,23}"
set ylabel "Free Energy (eV)"
set ylabel  font "{/:Bold,23}"
set xtic scale 0
set ytics out nomirror
set xtics nomirror
set xtics ("O_{2}" 0.3, "O@^*_{2}" 1.3, "OOH^*" 2.3  , "O^*" 3.3, "OH^*" 4.3 ,"H_{2}O" 5.3 ) font "{/:Bold},23"
set ytics font "{/:Bold},23"
## Last datafile plotted: "step-x"
p "step-1" u 7:8 w l dt 4 lc rgb 'blue' notitle, "step-1" u 2:3 w l lw 3 lc rgb 'blue' title "{/:Bold 0 V}"
rep "step-1" u 9:10 w l dt 4 lc rgb 'red' notitle, "step-1" u 4:5 w l lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "{/:Bold 0.84 V}"
#    EOF
```

Below is the data file

```
    #X-title     #X-U(0)      #X-U(1.8) #y-title  #y-U(0)        #y-U(1.8)
#1           #2  #3       #4    #5    #6      #7  #8        #9    #10
O_{2}        0   0        0   -3.00  O_{2}    0.5  0         0.5 -3.00
O@^*_{2}     0.5 0        0.5 -3.00  O_{2}    1   -0.1       1  -3.04

O@^*_{2}     1   -0.1     1   -3.04  OOH^*    1.5 -0.1       1.5  -3.04
OOH^*        1.5 -0.1     1.5 -3.04  OOH^*    2   -1.00      2  -3.12

OOH^*        2   -1.00    2   -3.12  O^*      2.5 -1.0       2.5  -3.12
O^*          2.5 -1.00    2.5 -3.12  O^*      3   -2.00      3    -4.00

O^*          3    -2.00   3    -4.00 OH^*     3.5 -2.00      3.5  -4.00
OH^*         3.5  -2.00   3.5  -4.00 OH^*     4   -4.00      4   -4.50

OH^*         4   -4.00    4   -4.50  H_{2}O   4.5 -4.00      4.5 -4.50
H_{2}O       4.5 -4.00    4.5 -4.50  H_{2}O   5   -4.50      5   -4.50

H_{2}O       5   -4.50    5   -4.50
H_{2}O       5.5 -4.50    5.5 -4.50
```

Comment: Before you continue to ask more questions, you might want to accept answers to your earlier questions (if they solved your issue) or clarify if the answers did not solve your problem.

Comment: Your script does not work because it is a mixture of Bash and Gnuplot scripts. Since your question is extensive, it would be easier to get an answer if you focused your question on what you really want to improve, with more simple example.

Comment: `for f1 in ./` does not do anything useful; what exactly do you want to loop over?

Comment: Use `read` to ask for user input.

Comment: I haven't used this stack overflow site before. I will see how to accept answers. Thanks @theozh and okay. For now, I am trying to just loop this Gnuplot script so that it can take the two input files and just product this plot. I have to make a total of 30 plots. I was told to make this into a for loop, whether thats the best way or not, I do not know.

Comment: @CourtneyBrea don't worry. I guess it is just not clear what exactly you want to do. My current understanding: you have files names with an index and you want to plot them all in one plot. Column 2:3 with title "0V" and column 4:5 with title "0.84V" in the legend. What is the index? From 1 to 30? What does the data look like? Do you want to have 1 output file per 2 input files, i.e. 30 output files? Or 1 output file with 30 plots? If you want 30 output files you would need and index for them as well. Your description is a bit confusing. Please clarify.

Comment: @theozh I tried to make it as simple as possible by rewriting the question. I compiled everything to one data file. Let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad that you added some data. This is essential for making reasonable suggestions.
However, I wouldn't call your data above "simplified". You basically ignored the suggestions from the answers to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73734395/7295599).
Your data structure here is horribly complicated and difficult to create and maintain. You can simplify the data to the absolute minimum, but well, then you have to put a little bit more effort into the plotting command.

Yes, you can create your 30 graphs in a loop (check `help do`), no need for bash.

- define functions for your input/output file names (check `help sprintf`).
- you have to set the output before the actual plotting command.

I hope you can adapt the example below to your needs.

**Data:** `SO73873363_step-1.dat`

Isn't this data format much smaller, clearer and easier to understand?

```
"Reaction Coordinate"  "0 V"   "0.84 V" 
O_{2}                   0      -3.00
O@^*_{2}               -0.1    -3.04
OOH^*                  -1.00   -3.12
O^*                    -2.00   -4.00
OH^*                   -4.00   -4.50
H_{2}O                 -4.50   -4.50
```

**Script:**

```
### create multiple output files from multiple input files
reset session

myFileIn(i)  = sprintf("SO73873363_step-%d.dat",i)
myFileOut(i) = sprintf("SO73873363_step-%d.svg",i)

set term svg font "Sans,20"

set border 15 front lt black linewidth 3.000 dashtype solid
set title "Associative Pathway (0,1)"
set xlabel "Reaction Coordinate"
set xrange [-0.5:5.5]
set xtics nomirror scale 0
set ylabel "Free Energy (eV)"
set yrange[-5:0.1]
set ytics out nomirror
set key noautotitle samplen 2
set errorbars 0
dx = 0.2

do for [i=1:30] {
    set output myFileOut(i)

    plot myFileIn(i) u 0:2:(dx):xtic(1) w xerr lc "blue" lw 3 ps 0 ti columnheader(2), \
                  '' u 0:3:(dx)         w xerr lc "red"  lw 3 ps 0 ti columnheader(3), \
        x1=y1=NaN '' u (x0=x1,x1=$0,x0-1+dx):(y0=y1,y1=$2,y0):(1-2*dx):(y1-y0) w vec dt 4 lc "blue" nohead, \
        x1=y1=NaN '' u (x0=x1,x1=$0,x0-1+dx):(y0=y1,y1=$3,y0):(1-2*dx):(y1-y0) w vec dt 4 lc "red" nohead
}
set output   # close the last file
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: hey @theozh I did not fully understand how it worked for the previous answer and did not want to bother you all ask for explanations so I figured I try to find a work around. I dont understand how you arrive at the code you had written. I also understand its a forum and not a classroom. I know my file looks messy but its what a step function looks like mapped out and yeah, I was trying to avoid "complicating' the code as my main concern is the chemistry and im a new and time crunched but I appreciate your time and effort with my issues. Thank you

Comment: @CourtneyBrea well, of course this is kind of a classroom, but not for the very basic and trivial questions which you can find by RT*M or on the gnuplot homepage or a web or a StackOverflow search. So, your first question was definitely not a trivial one. For creating output files in a loop there are a few examples here. Anyway, hopefully this example answered both of your questions at once. Always provide a short and precise description: 1. what do I have (data,script)? 2. what do I want (graph)? 3. What have I tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I used your code to generate the plots. Issue I am having is that the xtic text has gaps between the subscripts and superscripts. Unfortunately I cant show you since I cant post pictures. Not sure how to fix this issue. I tried to play with the terminal settings but that doesn't work.

Comment: @CourtneyBrea which terminal are you using and which operating system? I thought with >10 Reputation you should be able to add images. Maybe create a new question with a **minimal** example and try to add an image. It's difficult to say without your script and your image. Maybe it has to do something with the terminal and the huge font size 20 or 23. Without example which we can reproduce it is difficult.

Comment: I made a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73962148/xtic-text-has-gaps-how-can-i-adjust-the-terminal-svg-font-to-avoid-this