# I want to edit my script so it takes a single input file containing 31 sets of data and gives back 31 uniquely named output svg files

Tags: bash, svg, gnuplot

I would like to keep all the data organized in one single file to avoid having 31 input files, while generating 31 separate output svg files. Additionally I need the output file names to correspond to the name given in the input file, i.e. output file example name "1-1.svg", where the digits are subject to change. An example of the input file would look like the following:

```
"0-3" #name of svg file
"Reaction Coordinate"  "0 V"   "0.79 V"
O_{2}                   0      -3.17
O@^*_{2}               -0.21   -3.39
OOH^*                  -1.01   -3.39
O^*                    -2.60   -4.19
OH^*                   -4.12   -4.92
H_{2}O                 -4.92   -4.92


"1-1"  #name of svg file 
"Reaction Coordinate"  "0 V"   "0.25 V"
O_{2}                   0      -3.17
O@^*_{2}               -0.21   -3.39
OOH^*                  -1.01   -3.39
O^*                    -2.60   -4.19
OH^*                   -4.12   -4.92
H_{2}O                 -4.92   -4.92


"2-5" #name of svg file 
"Reaction Coordinate"  "0 V"   "0.14 V"
O_{2}                   0      -3.17
O@^*_{2}               -0.21   -3.39
OOH^*                  -1.01   -3.39
O^*                    -2.60   -4.19
OH^*                   -4.12   -4.92
H_{2}O                 -4.92   -4.92
```

As for the script itself, this is what it looks like below. From what I imagine, the for loop portion has to be adjusted and the `myFileIn(i)  = sprintf("%d.dat",i)`can likely be changed to `myFileIn = sprint("total.dat")` possibly. As for the `myFileOut(i) = sprintf("%d.svg",i)` I am not sure.

```
myFileIn(i)  = sprintf("%d.dat",i)
myFileOut(i) = sprintf("%d.svg",i)

set term svg font "{/:Bold}Sans,25"
makebold(text) = sprintf("{/:Bold %s}", text)
set border 15 front lt black linewidth 3.000 dashtype solid
set xlabel "Reaction Coordinate"
set xrange [-0.2:5.2]
set xtics nomirror scale 0
set ylabel "Free Energy (eV)"
set ylabel offset character 1.3,0,0 font "{/:Bold},25"
set xlabel offset character 0,0.6,0 font "{/:Bold},25"
set yrange[-5:0.1]
set ytics in nomirror font "{/:Bold},25"
set key noautotitle samplen 2
set key enhanced
set errorbars 0
dx = 0.2

do for [i=1:4] {
    set output myFileOut(i)

    plot myFileIn(i) u 0:2:(dx):xtic(makebold(strcol(1))) w xerr lc "blue" lw 3 ps 0 ti columnheader(2), \
                  '' u 0:3:(dx)         w xerr lc "red"  lw 3 ps 0 ti columnheader(3), \
        x1=y1=NaN '' u (x0=x1,x1=$0,x0-1+dx):(y0=y1,y1=$2,y0):(1-2*dx):(y1-y0) w vec dt 4 lc "blue" nohead, \
        x1=y1=NaN '' u (x0=x1,x1=$0,x0-1+dx):(y0=y1,y1=$3,y0):(1-2*dx):(y1-y0) w vec dt 4 lc "red" nohead
}
set output   # close the last file
### end of script
```

Comment: Gnuplot is pesky in that regard. I vaguely remember generating the plot code for each image with a shell script and then removing the plot code when I was done. A simple shell script with a here document would easily let you create a template where you fill in a few values from shell variables. Just take care to backslash-escape any dollar signs (and backslashes and backticks \`) which should be visible to Gnuplot. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54434993

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some small changes are required to your script.
Luckily, you have the data separated by two empty lines. With this, you can simply address the subblocks via `index` (check `help index`). Furthermore, you can (mis)use `stats` to extract some numbers or strings without plotting anything. You limit the the extraction to the i-th block (`index i`) and the first row of that block (`every ::::0`), check `help every`. Indices are zero-based.

**Data:** `SO77565285.dat`

```
"0-3" #name of svg file
"Reaction Coordinate"  "0 V"   "0.79 V"
O_{2}                   0      -3.17
O@^*_{2}               -0.21   -3.39
OOH^*                  -1.01   -3.39
O^*                    -2.60   -4.19
OH^*                   -4.12   -4.92
H_{2}O                 -4.92   -4.92


"1-1"  #name of svg file 
"Reaction Coordinate"  "0 V"   "0.25 V"
O_{2}                   0      -3.17
O@^*_{2}               -0.21   -3.39
OOH^*                  -1.01   -3.39
O^*                    -2.60   -4.19
OH^*                   -4.12   -4.92
H_{2}O                 -4.92   -4.92


"2-5" #name of svg file 
"Reaction Coordinate"  "0 V"   "0.14 V"
O_{2}                   0      -3.17
O@^*_{2}               -0.21   -3.39
OOH^*                  -1.01   -3.39
O^*                    -2.60   -4.19
OH^*                   -4.12   -4.92
H_{2}O                 -4.92   -4.92
```

**Script:**

```
### create multiple SVG files from multiple subblocks
reset session

FILE = "SO77565285.dat"
set term svg font "{/:Bold}Sans,25"
makebold(text) = sprintf("{/:Bold %s}", text)
set border 15 front lt black linewidth 3.000 dashtype solid
set xlabel "Reaction Coordinate"
set xrange [-0.2:5.2]
set xtics nomirror scale 0
set ylabel "Free Energy (eV)"
set ylabel offset character 1.3,0,0 font "{/:Bold},25"
set xlabel offset character 0,0.6,0 font "{/:Bold},25"
set yrange[-5:0.1]
set ytics in nomirror font "{/:Bold},25"
set key noautotitle samplen 2
set key enhanced
set errorbars 0
dx = 0.2
myFileOut(s) = sprintf("%s.svg",s)

do for [i=0:2] {
    stats FILE index i every ::::0 u (s=strcol(1),0) nooutput
    set output myFileOut(s)

    plot        FILE skip 1 index i u 0:2:(dx):xtic(makebold(strcol(1))) w xerr lc "blue" lw 3 ps 0 ti columnheader(2), \
                  '' skip 1 index i u 0:3:(dx)         w xerr lc "red"  lw 3 ps 0 ti columnheader(3), \
        x1=y1=NaN '' skip 1 index i u (x0=x1,x1=$0,x0-1+dx):(y0=y1,y1=$2,y0):(1-2*dx):(y1-y0) w vec dt 4 lc "blue" nohead, \
        x1=y1=NaN '' skip 1 index i u (x0=x1,x1=$0,x0-1+dx):(y0=y1,y1=$3,y0):(1-2*dx):(y1-y0) w vec dt 4 lc "red" nohead
}
set output   # close the last file
### end of script
```

**Result:** (just one file: `0-3.svg`)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply @theozh so I fixed the reason it came out a little wonky by adjusting s=strcol(1) to s = strcol(4) where I made "1-1" its own column. It worked. I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: @CourtneyBrea sorry, I didn't pay attention to the legend... but I hope you can fix it.

Comment: no please, you did great. I did fix it and even applied some of this code to another script I have. Thank you again for coming to the rescue.

Comment: @CourtneyBrea a simple `skip 1` in the plotting command skips the first line where the filename was extracted earlier via `stats`, and hence the second line is considered as columnheader and used for the legend.

Comment: oh ok thanks for the additional input @theozh

Comment: I recently took this script and tried to it in emf terminal setting but the solid red and blue lines are split in two and I am not sure how to fix this format setting. do you need me to upload the code? I think I have to adjust the spacing maybe? I am not sure